# java regex match for alphanumeric string

Tags: java, regex, match

I am trying to check whether a password is alphanumeric or not using regex
but I am not getting the result I expect. What is the problem with the below code?

```
boolean passwordOnlyAlphaNumericCheck = false;
Pattern patternAlphaNumericCheck = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9]$");
Matcher matcherAlphaNumericCheck = patternAlphaNumericCheck.matcher(login.getPassword());
if(matcherAlphaNumericCheck.find())
  passwordOnlyAlphaNumericCheck = true;
```

Thanks for help

Comment: `"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"` or `"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*"` - you forgot the quantifier. And you can remove the `^` and `$` and use `.matches()`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works when i use `login.getPassword().matches("[0-9a-zA-Z]*");` but what is the difference between `login.getPassword().matches("[0-9a-zA-Z]*");` and `login.getPassword().matches("[0-9a-zA-Z]");`

Comment: See more explanations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a quantifier that suits your requirements: `*` - 0 or more occurrences or `+` - 1 or more occurrences. You can also omit the `^` and `$` and use [**`String.matches()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)):

```
boolean passwordOnlyAlphaNumericCheck = false;
if(login.getPassword().matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]*"))
  passwordOnlyAlphaNumericCheck = true;
```

To match all Unicode letters, use `\p{L}` class (and perhaps, `\p{M}` to match diacritics): `"[\\p{L}\\p{M}0-9]+"`.

> what is the difference between `login.getPassword().matches("[0-9a-zA-Z]*");` and `login.getPassword().matches("[0-9a-zA-Z]");`?

The `.matches("[0-9a-zA-Z]")` will only return true if the whole string contains just *1 digit or letter*. The `*` in `[0-9a-zA-Z]*` will allow an empty string, or a string *having* zero or more letters/digits.

Answer (score 3):

use this `regex` expression Take a [Demo Here For Regex](https://ideone.com/Xr9keP)

`"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$ "` Or `"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"`

instead of

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9]$ // * or + should be added at last
```

So, This might work to you

```
Pattern patternAlphaNumericCheck = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
```

OR

```
Pattern patternAlphaNumericCheck = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern will only match strings with **one** alphanumeric character, since you have no quantifier and match explicitly from start (`^`) to end (`$`).

Append `+` for 1+ matches, or `*` for 0+ matches to your character class.

You can also use the script: `\\p{Alnum}` instead of a tedious character class.

For instance:

- `^\\p{Alnum}{8}$` will match a `String` made of **8** alphanumeric characters
- `^\\p{Alnum}{8,}$` will match a `String` made of **8 or more** alphanumeric characters
- `^\\p{Alnum}{8,10}$` will match a `String` made of **8 to 10** alphanumeric characters
- `^\\p{Alnum}+$` will match a `String` made of **1 or more** alnums
- `^\\p{Alnum}*$` will match an **empty** `String` or a `String` made of **any number** of alnums

Answer (score 2):

This function will help ensure that you have just alphanumeric as wanted.

```
public static boolean isAlphanumeric(String value){
    if (isValueEmpty(value)) {
        return false;
    }

    return value.matches("^[a-zA-Z_0-9]*$");
}

public static boolean isValueEmpty(String param){
    return param == null || param.isEmpty();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regexp:

```
private final String nonAlphanumericRegex = ".*\\W.*";
if (Pattern.matches(nonAlphanumericRegex, YOUR_STRING))
    throw IllegalArgumentException()
```