# Check if a string is alphanumeric

Tags: android

I'm trying to check if a string is alphanumeric or not. I tried many things given in other posts but to no avail. I tried StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(), a library from Apache Commons but failed. I tried regex also from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533474/java-how-to-test-if-a-string-contains-both-letter-and-number) but that too didn't worked. Is there a method to check if a string is alphanumeric and returns true or false according to it?

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String text = fullnameet.getText().toString();
                String numRegex   = ".*[0-9].*";
                String alphaRegex = ".*[A-Z].*";

                if (text.matches(numRegex) && text.matches(alphaRegex)) {
                    System.out.println("Its Alphanumeric");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Its NOT Alphanumeric");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if a String has non-alphanumeric characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248277/how-to-determine-if-a-string-has-non-alphanumeric-characters)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java regex match for alphanumeric string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37070161/java-regex-match-for-alphanumeric-string) ... there are so many SO questions about this, have you tried spending 5 minutes searching?

Comment: Yes, I've already mentioned I've searched many SO posts but not any one is working for me.

Comment: If you write an extension method for strings, the check can be built in.  You could also use one that's already written such as the [Extensions.cs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extensions.cs) NuGet package that makes it as simple as: For example: "abcXYZ".IsAlphabetic() will return True whereas "abc123".IsAlphabetic() will return False.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to ascertain that your string is both alphanumeric *and* contains both numbers and letters, then you can use the following logic:

```
.*[A-Za-z].*   check for the presence of at least one letter
.*[0-9].*      check for the presence of at least one number
[A-Za-z0-9]*   check that only numbers and letters compose this string

String text = fullnameet.getText().toString();
if (text.matches(".*[A-Za-z].*") && text.matches(".*[0-9].*") && text.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]*")) {
    System.out.println("Its Alphanumeric");
} else {
    System.out.println("Its NOT Alphanumeric");
}
```

Note that we *could* handle this with a single regex but it would likely be verbose and possibly harder to maintain than the above answer.

Comment: I already tried your code. It prints "Its Alphanumeric" even if I enter just alphabets @Tim

Comment: Um..."just alphabets" is alphanumeric.  Are you looking for a string which has both letters _and_ numbers?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I need to check if the string contains both alphabets and numbers. Combination of both is called alphanumeric. @Tim

Comment: @SomnathPal I updated my answer with something which should work for you.  It's not the prettiest code, but it's logically correct.

Comment: Why not just `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`?

Answer (score 2):

Original from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831719/fastest-way-to-check-a-string-is-alphanumeric-in-java)

String myString = "qwerty123456";
System.out.println(myString.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]+"));

```
String myString = "qwerty123456";

if(myString.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]+"))
{
    System.out.println("Alphanumeric");
}
if(myString.matches("[A-Za-z]+"))
{
    System.out.println("Alphabet");
```

}

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
            boolean hasSpecialChar = p.matcher(edittext.getText().toString()).find();

            if (!edittext.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                if (hasSpecialChar) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "not Alphanumeric", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Its Alphanumeric", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Empty value of edit text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: That's also not working. Its showing Toast of "Its Alphanumeric" every time @Nilesh

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to check if the string is alphanumeric or not. For more details check [Fastest way to check a string is alphanumeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12832035/6452629)

```
public class QuickTest extends TestCase {

    private final int reps = 1000000;



    public void testRegexp() {
        for(int i = 0; i < reps; i++)
            ("ab4r3rgf"+i).matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]");
    }



    public void testIsAlphanumeric2() {
        for(int i = 0; i < reps; i++)
            isAlphanumeric2("ab4r3rgf"+i);
    }



    public boolean isAlphanumeric2(String str) {
        for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            if (c < 0x30 || (c >= 0x3a && c <= 0x40) || (c > 0x5a && c <= 0x60) || c > 0x7a)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

While there are many ways to skin this cat, I prefer to wrap such code into reusable extension methods that make it trivial to do going forward.  When using extension methods, you can also avoid RegEx as it is slower than a direct character check.  I like using the extensions in the Extensions.cs NuGet package.  It makes this check as simple as:

1. Add the https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extensions.cs package to your project.
2. Add "`using Extensions;`" to the top of your code.
3. `"smith23@".IsAlphaNumeric()` will return False whereas `"smith23".IsAlphaNumeric()` will return True.  By default the `.IsAlphaNumeric()` method ignores spaces, but it can also be overridden such that `"smith 23".IsAlphaNumeric(false)` will return False since the space is not considered part of the alphabet.
4. Every other check in the rest of the code is simply `MyString.IsAlphaNumeric()`.

Your example code would become as simple as:

```
using Extensions;

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String text = fullnameet.getText().toString();
            //String numRegex   = ".*[0-9].*";
            //String alphaRegex = ".*[A-Z].*";

            //if (text.matches(numRegex) && text.matches(alphaRegex)) {
            if (text.IsAlphaNumeric()) {
                System.out.println("Its Alphanumeric");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Its NOT Alphanumeric");
            }
        }
    });
```